# Send variable value in a webhook

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, webhooks

I am trying to send a variable value pulled from a spreadsheet in a webhook, my issue is that i am not being able to pass the variable value in the "data variable", when i only send pure text, everything works fine but the variable value is not arriving, as it simple as it may sound, can anyone guide me on this matter? Thanks in advance.

```
function message (){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Backlog Report");
  var backlogValue = ws.getRange("U7").getValue();
  var totalCases = ws.getRange("Z7").getValue();
console.log(backlogValue);
var data = {
  text: "Backlog: " + backlogValue
};

var payload = JSON.stringify(data);

var options = {
  method: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
  payload: payload,
  muteHttpExceptions: true
};

var webhook = 'https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/XXXX/messages?key=XXX';
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(webhook, options);
Logger.log(response.getContentText());

}
```

Comment: What does U7 contain? Does your payload look correct?

Comment: its a number value being store in the backlogValue variable, I am not that much familiar with webhooks therefore i am not sure it is correct

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with webhooks as well... i can't tell you exactly why the following works for me, but if it helps you solve your problem, then here you go with my function. I've used it to send google sheets data to one of my Discord Channels with a embed format.

I think the relevant part of this is, to get the value of a field

```
var docName = sheets.getRange('B2').getValue();
```

Full Function:

```
//Discord webhook Aktiv-Recruitment

function postMessageToDiscord() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var docName = sheets.getRange('B2').getValue();
  var docRealm = sheets.getRange('C2').getValue();
  var docClass = sheets.getRange('D2').getValue();
  var docBtag = sheets.getRange('J2').getValue();
  var docProg = sheets.getRange('I2').getValue();
  var docDate = sheets.getRange('K2').getValue();


var discordUrl = "YOUR_WEBHOOK_URL";

`changed to var payload = {content:message} and received the new error` 
var payload = JSON.stringify({
  "embeds": [{
      "author":{
        "name": docClass + " hinzugefügt!",
      },
  "title": docBtag,
      "color": 15374745,
      "url" : "SOME_LINK",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "Name",
          "value": docName,
          "inline": true
        },
        {
          "name": "Realm",
          "value": docRealm,
          "inline": true
        },
          {
          "name": "Progress",
          "value": docProg
        }
        ],
             "footer": {
        "text": docDate
      }
  }] 
 });
 


var params = {
  
  method: "POST",
  payload: payload,
  muteHttpExceptions : true,
  contentType: "application/json"
};

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(discordUrl, params);

  Logger.log(response.getContentText());

}
```